# How to split CString into characters?

Tags: c++, mfc

i have this CString:
"0 2 8 27 29 32 35 48 52 55 58 62 72"
and i need to put each number to a separate element of an array.
can someone please help me with this?
-ThanX

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Not sure if bad question or bad english... do you mean you want 13 different arrays? And what would have to be the type of those arrays?

Comment: I recommend looking at the `CString` class to see if there are any *substring*, *find* or parsing methods.  Extract the number then convert it.

Comment: Int array or CString array? And does it really have to be an array? Vector is much more usable in C++.

Comment: @SimoErkinheimo int array would be better. it's part of a homework project, and it would be better if i don't use vector(our teacher never used that before) - thnks for your help <3

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want those numbers to array of integers. std::vector might be nicer to use.

```
std::vector<int> oResult;
CString oMyStr = _T("0 2 8 27 29 32 35 48 52 55 58 62 72");

int iIndex = 0;
CString oToken = oMyStr.Tokenize(_T(" "), iIndex); // Tokenize with space

while ( !oToken.IsEmpty() )
{
    try
    {
        int iNbr = atoi( oToken );
        oResult.push_back(iNbr);
    }
    catch (...) { } // This is bad code, but I'm just lazy.

    oToken = oMyStr.Tokenize(_T(" "), iIndex); // Tokenize with space
}
```

In case you really want **an array**, you can convert the vector with

```
int* pPointerToArraysFirstElement = &oResult[0];
```

However, that might crash in case the vector is empty.

Comment: You have had way too much exposure to Java to be healthy. Drop the try-catch handler, it doesn't do anything useful. The only operation that does throw an exception is `oResult.push_back`. If you're running out of memory, don't just silently ignore it. Have the application terminate, or let a downstream exception handler deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to separate the individual elements into a vector of strings, where each element is put as a separate element.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

vector<string> &split(const string &s, char delim, vector<string> &elems) {
    stringstream ss(s);
    string item;
    while (getline(ss, item, delim)) {
        elems.push_back(item);
    }
    return elems;
}

vector<string> split(const string &s, char delim) {
    vector<string> elems;
    split(s, delim, elems);
    return elems;
}

int main()
{
    string s = "0 2 8 27 29 32 35 48 52 55 58 62 72";
    vector<string> elemsVec = split(s, ' ');
    vector<string>::iterator it;
    for(it = elemsVec.begin(); it != elemsVec.end(); ++it)
        cout << *it << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

Output:
    0
    2
    8
    27
    29
    32
    35
    48
    52
    55
    58
    62
    72

Comment: Thnk you bro, but I'm working with MFC, can I still use them?